# @Transactional not working with @EnableIntegration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-data-jpa, transactional

We have a spring data jpa application in which we are trying to replace a workflow   using "Spring Integration". We are using java configuration. As soon as we add a configuration which has @EnableIntegration, @Transactional stops working and we get errors like:

```
    org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.kronos.authz.impl.entity.Role.faps, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

The application works fine if we remove @EnableIntegration from the configuration.The configuration we are adding is:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.xyz.integration.endPoint")              
@IntegrationComponentScan("com.xyz.tenantprovision.integration.endPoint")       
@EnableIntegration

public class TenantProvisioningConfig {

@Bean
@Description("Entry to the messaging system through the gateway.")
public MessageChannel incomingProvisioningRequest() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
}

@Bean
@Description("Sends request messages to the web service outbound gateway")
public MessageChannel activatedChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@Description("Sends web service responses to both the client and a database")
public MessageChannel requestJsonChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
@Description("Stores non filtered messages to the database")
public MessageChannel acknowledgementChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}    
}
```

The main application configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"com.xyz"})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement(mode=AdviceMode.PROXY,proxyTargetClass=true)
public class ConfigApplicationContext {
//datasource initialization code etc

}
```

The stacktrace is:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [CXFServlet] in context with path [/tenantmanager] threw exception
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.xyz.authz.impl.entity.Role.faps, could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:575)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:214)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
        at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1798)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:270)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
        at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
        at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:512)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
        at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
        at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

**EDIT:**
As mentioned by @ArtemBilan in comments, this appears to be an "early BeanFactory access syndrome". The flow is

org.springframework.integration.expression.IntegrationEvaluationContextAwareBeanPostProcessor#0 -> org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor -> org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration -> metaDataSourceAdvisor , interface org.springframework.aop.Advisor -> methodSecurityMetadataSource

methodSecurityMetadataSource now tries to create a bean in our application which is a configuration extending GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration. It overrides MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler(). From here it goes on to access services defined to provide user details. These services have @Transactional annotated methods. These methods when used later in the code give error for not being in Transaction.

Comment: It would be great to see more StackTrace on the matter. And even better some simple application from somewhere on GitHub to play from our side. Just because all this does not make sense and doesn't ring a bell. Typically `LazyInitializationException` happens when you move your entity from one thread to another without `session` propagation. That's why that thread can't retrieve lazy-load collection.

Comment: I don't know enough about spring integration to know what is going on here.  However, the way `@Transactional` works is that Spring will create a dynamic proxy of the bean that has `@Transactional` methods.  Is it possible spring integration is replacing this proxied beans with other beans?  Is it possible spring integration is accessing your data somewhere it previously was not, where no transaction is active (e.g. `@Transactional` works fine but the access is outside the transaction)?  Put a breakpoint in the constructor of the bean that has `@Transactional` methods, who is creating it?

Comment: @ArtemBilan ,  added stacktrace, I will create a simple application and put it on github. Thanks.

Comment: So, how about the application to play? How does it work without `proxyTargetClass=true`, BTW ? Plus would you mind to share the code/config which causes that  `LazyInitializationException` in your `CXFServlet` ?

Comment: I am sorry, so far I could not reproduce the issue in a separate sample application. In the main application itself I tried to use xml configuration for spring integration part only and imported it using @ImportResource in java configuration. was still giving the same error. Then I added <tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true"/> to the xml config. Things do work fine with this change but the strange thing is that after some time LazyInitializationException  starts coming again.

Comment: @ArtemBilan when I use EnableIntegration, I get below in logs: "org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker","msg":"Bean 'com.xyz.authz.impl.service.GroupServiceImpl' of type [class com.xyz.authz.impl.service.GroupServiceImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)" . GroupServiceImpl is the bean where I have Transactional. does this help in finding the cause ?

Comment: Well it's definitely guilty. We called that "early BeanFactory access syndrome". Share its code and we'll try to help to eliminate the issue.

Comment: @ArtemBilan Updated the question with additional info. Right now I don't have shareable code. Jira INT-3640 talks about similar issue. It is fixed in 4.2. we are using spring 4.1.4. Do we need to upgrade as the issue comes only with EnableIntegration.

Comment: Yes, it is the issue... It's never bad to upgrade having such a problem!